# d3dx9_43.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: windows, directx

According to `dxdiag`, the directx version of my system is 11

```
 Operating System: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.120830-0333)
 Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
 System Manufacturer: Sony Corporation
 System Model: VGN-SR250J
 BIOS: BIOS Date: 06/04/08 14:30:19 Ver: 08.00.10
 Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8400  @ 2.26GHz (2 CPUs), ~2.3GHz
 Memory: 4096MB RAM
 Available OS Memory: 3934MB RAM
 Page File: 2057MB used, 5810MB available
 Windows Dir: C:\Windows
 DirectX Version: DirectX 11
 DX Setup Parameters: Not found
 User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
 DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
 DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 32bit Unicode
```

However, when I want to run a game, I get this error

```
 The program can't start because d3dx9_43.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

Indeed there is no `d3dx9_43.dll` in `c:\windows`!!!! So how can I fix that? I don't want to download and install the dll file from internet and paste it to windows folder.

Comment: Try using this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35

Comment: you mean downgrading 11 to 9?

Comment: @mahmood - DirectX 9 and 11 can both exist on the same sysstem.  In the end you don't have compatabile DirextX installed.  Its typical to install the exact version of the dll that is needed by the game to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [DirectX Web Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35). It will download optional DirectX components, including previous runtime DLL versions that are required by some legacy applications.

The installer was published in 2011 (long after DirectX 11 was released) and is listed as compatible with Windows 7. Additionally, as a web installer it downloads the files it needs when you actually run it meaning it is always kept up to date. So don't be concerned that it will somehow mess up DirectX 11 - it worked fine when I ran it.

Comment: Is there a direct link to this installer? The provided link just takes me to a page where I'm prompted to upgrade to Windows 10 (I'm already running Windows 10)

Comment: @MattDavey: I don't think that the web installer works correctly for Windows 10 as DirectX has changed a bit. There is a different question http://superuser.com/questions/979687/how-can-i-install-directx9-on-windows-10 for Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Programs that require specific updated version of DirectX usually ship with its redistributable installer(Especially true with games. In most of the cases, there would be `redist` directory in game installation media.).
It should be somewhere on the installation media. Install it and you should be fine.

Of course, you can also use the web installer as suggested by @James